# Rails: How do I turn off timestamps on my CSS and JS assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to remove the timestamps generated by rails caching on my CSS and JS files. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: do you know why they exist?

Comment: so that they are cached properly? they are generated based on the content of the file so if i change them the timestamp changes and therefore the new one is loaded. right?

Comment: And, without the digest, once a browser caches the asset, it either won't reload them unless you set the proper headers, in which cause it will try and load them on every request, making the page take longer to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn off the digest that is appended to filenames during assets precompile set `config.assets.debug = false` in `config/application.rb` or in the relevant environment config.

It's noted at the bottom of this section of the rails guides.

[Asset Digests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care)

Comment: oh lol, you really should mention that your using software that old. There is no digest in Rails 2. This wasn't introduced until rails 3.1